# Remove a specific item (index) method

Tags: javascript, angular

So I have a list of phones that I add new input lines to, and I have a remove method set, for each individual row.

This is the template:

```
 <div formArrayName="mobiles">
    <div *ngFor="let mobile of mobiles.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center" [class.pt-4]="i > 0">
            <input class="input" type="text" formControlName="phone">
            <a class="input-remove ml-3">
                <i class="icon icon-trash h3 text-primary" (click)="removeMobile()"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And these are my methods that are within the respective component:

```
get mobiles(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get("mobiles") as FormArray;
}

get stations(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get("stations") as FormArray;
}

addMobile() {
    this.mobiles.push(this.fb.group(new PhoneFormGroup()));
}

addStation() {
    this.stations.push(this.fb.group(new PhoneFormGroup()));
}

removeMobile(index: number) {
    this.mobiles.removeAt(index);
    if (this.mobiles.controls.length == 0) {
        this.addMobile();
    }
}

removeStation(index: number) {
    this.stations.removeAt(index);
    if (this.mobiles.controls.length == 0) {
        this.addStation();
    }
}
```

The problem here is, that whenever I click on the delete button, it deletes the first item(index[0]) from the list, and I want it to delete the specific item I have selected for deletion.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't pass `index` param to `removeMobile` function from your HTML template.

```
<i class="icon icon-trash h3 text-primary" (click)="removeMobile(i)"></i>
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem there. I should pay more attention, but you know how big projects go sometimes.

Thank You!

Comment: Yes, sometimes a snippet need a quick peek from another! Welcome!

Comment: @jo1storm , there was a 10 minute restriction on that one at the specific moment, as you already know. Now it's done. :)

Comment: @Zooly , as you can see, from a slight read it looks like it has the `i` inside it, because of the closing `</i>` tag. `(click)="removeMobile()"></i>`

Comment: Indeed! Maybe not name your iterator with simple letters, but maybe something more explicit

Comment: sorry about that, didn't see the 10 minute restriction.